# 4K videos on YouTube are a little choppy on high-end specs

Tags: windows-7, video, youtube, lag, 4k-resolution

I've watched various videos, and it's the latest version of Flash and all appropriate settings.

I turn the videos up to 4K (2160P) and they chop a little bit ... like every frame isn't smoothly seen.

Also, I am using a 50 MB internet connection, but the video buffers non-stop and barely plays.

CPU: i3-4160.

GPU: HD 4400.

OS: Windows 7.

CPU has a Passmark of almost 2,100, 4 cores (with hyperthreading), and 3 MB cache. I believe the CPU can't really be bottlenecked by 4K video streaming. Could the GPU be struggling in this case?

I don't know how much of the CPU vs. GPU Flash Player uses, but 1440P plays 100% perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

There's a good chance it's a combination of your internet connection and the fact that your not using a graphics card that is causing the playback buffering and stuttering.

Something else to keep in mind is that internet connection speeds are typically measured in Mb (Megabits) as opposed to MB (Megabytes) so if your connection speed is actually 50 Mb/s that's only 6.125 MB/s.

Comment: It is an integrated graphics processing unit, and it's not too bad. Does Flash depend more on the GPU or the CPU when doing high-res. video streaming/playback?

Comment: Flash uses hardware acceleration that utilizes the GPU.  The drawback with integrated graphics is it shares resources with the CPU which can affect performance.  If you have a dedicated GPU separate from your CPU there's less chance of a bottleneck.

Comment: But there are much better integrated graphics than the HD 4400 anyways; so it's not really the fact that it's integrated but also it's not very powerful from square one. Anyhow, the GPU can run PS2/GameCube/etc. emulation, and it's not really useful to watch 4K on an old monitor like mine, so thanks anyways.

Comment: And the only resource it shares is RAM & I have 4 GB, so that's not the issue; it's the GPU's "power." Since it's powerful enough for what I do (emulation, video editing, 3D modelling), 4K video playback's not mandatory.